# Using Moss as a virtual sysadmin. Based on this image and text, is it creating DNS entries?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, vps

I've just set up a new site on a VPS using Moss as a virtual sysadmin.

In Moss' control panel, I can see A and CNAME records.

As an example, you can see them at the bottom of this image from their support page:

[image]

You can't tell from the picture, but these are live DNS entries--not just text examples. You can edit, delete, and add more. And, the changes are reflected in tools like DNS checker.

But, elsewhere, Moss says, "Moss doesn't create any DNS record. Instead, it tells you the records you should create in your DNS provider to have your site(s) online."

To me, this feels like a contradiction--as the Moss panel allows me to create DNS records but the support is saying that Moss cannot create DNS records.

Is this a contradiction? Or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Do you control your nameservers? If so, then a panel might be able to configure them based on records you want. If not, because nameservers are under someone else administration, then no record panel could really configure them, just show what to do put into them. So your question lacks those details at least.

Comment: To answer your question, the site is hosted at Upcloud (which does not provide name servers), the domain is registered with Google Domains (whose name servers I'm presently using), and--based on the image and quoted text above--I can't tell if Moss has added an additional set of name servers to my server. If this puts my question into clearer context, I'd love to hear your hunch. Thanks again!